# Sync Issue from Phone to Gmail contacrs

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, google-account

I deleted all my contacts from my android phone But have all of them in my gmail account,

> What will happen if i sync my accounts ?

means

> It will copy all contacts to phone or delete all contacts from gmail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to remove the account and then reconnect to it.
It however, is likely to have already synced and removed these contacts.